# can only concatenate str (not list) to str

Tags: python

I keep getting "can only concatenate str (not list) to str" but i'm not sure why i'm getting this error. I'm fairly new to python so any help would be appreciated.

```
def oldMacdonald():
    return "Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!\n"

def verseFor(animal, sound):
    lyrics = oldMacdonald() + "And on his farm he had a " + animal + ", Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!\n" \
        "With a " + sound + ", " + sound + " here and a " + sound + ", " \
        "" + sound + ".\nHere a " + sound + ", there a " + sound + ", " \
        "everywhere a " + sound + ", " + sound + "\n" + oldMacdonald()

    return lyrics

def main():
    sound = ["moo", "oink", "neigh", "cluck", "bahh"]
    for animal in ["cow", "pig", "horse", "chick", "sheep"]:
        print(verseFor(animal, sound))

main()
```

Comment: yeah,only can concatenate str to str.....and what do you want to do?

Comment: `sound` variable inside the function `verseFor()` is list, that's where you are getting the error.

Comment: It looks like you intended to pass one animal and one sound to `verseFor()`, but you're actually passing one animal and the _entire list_ of sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Basically, in this block of code

```py
sound = ["moo", "oink", "neigh", "cluck", "bahh"]
    for animal in ["cow", "pig", "horse", "chick", "sheep"]:
        print(verseFor(animal, sound))
```

`sound` is a list and `animal` is iterating over a list, i.e animal is single elements of the list meaning `cow` in 1st iteration, `pig` in 2nd, `horse` in 3rd and so on.

But you are passing `sound` as a whole list, not single elements of it, in `verseFor`.

So You have to iterate over both lists to send their animal and sound element by element. As mentioned, you can use `zip` like this.

```py
sound = ["moo", "oink", "neigh", "cluck", "bahh"]
animal = ["cow", "pig", "horse", "chick", "sheep"]
for ani, sou in zip(animal, sound):
    print(verseFor(ani, sou))
```

Now you are looping over both elements of sound and animals. If you look the output of `zip`, you get this.

```
list(zip(animal,sound))
>>>[('cow', 'moo'),
 ('pig', 'oink'),
 ('horse', 'neigh'),
 ('chick', 'cluck'),
 ('sheep', 'bahh')]
```

So basically in the first iteration in the code I provided, we are passing `cow` in `ani` and `moo` in `sou`. Then in the next iteration `pig` and `oink` respectively and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the error in my thought process as well as for explaining the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use zip

```py
animals = ["cow", "pig", "horse", "chick", "sheep"]
sounds = ["moo", "oink", "neigh", "cluck", "bahh"]
for animal, sound in zip(animals, sounds):
  print(verseFor(animal, sound))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ...

```
def oldMacdonald():
    return "Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!\n"

def verseFor(animal, sound):
    lyrics = oldMacdonald() + "And on his farm he had a " + animal + ", Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!\n" \
                                                                        "With a " + sound + ", " + sound + " here and a " + sound + ", " \
                                                                                                                                             "" + sound + ".\nHere a " + sound + ", there a " + sound + ", " \
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "everywhere a " + sound + ", " + sound + "\n" + oldMacdonald()

    return lyrics

def main():
    for animal,sound in zip(["cow", "pig", "horse", "chick", "sheep"],["moo", "oink", "neigh", "cluck", "bahh"]):
        print(verseFor(animal, sound))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the actual question is that you need to iterate over both lists together using `zip`.

However, separately, it bothers me that it prints "a oink". Here is a version that will print "an oink" -- the `a` function returns a word preceded by the appropriate indefinite article ("a" or "an").

```
def oldMacdonald():
    return "Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!"

def a(thing):
    if thing[0] in 'aeiou':
        return f'an {thing}'
    else:
        return f'a {thing}'

def verseFor(animal, sound):
    an_animal = a(animal)
    a_sound = a(sound)

    lyrics = f"""{oldMacdonald()}
And on his farm he had {an_animal}, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
With {a_sound}, {sound} here and {a_sound}, {sound} there.
Here {a_sound}, there {a_sound}, everywhere {a_sound}, {sound}.
{oldMacdonald()}
"""
    return lyrics

def main():
    sounds = ["moo", "oink", "neigh", "cluck", "bahh"]
    animals = ["cow", "pig", "horse", "chick", "sheep"]

    for animal, sound in zip(animals, sounds):
        print(verseFor(animal, sound))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    sound = ["moo", "oink", "neigh", "cluck", "bahh"]
    for animal in ["cow", "pig", "horse", "chick", "sheep"]:
        print(verseFor(animal, sound))
```

the problem is with sound dict. here is a quick fix:

```
def main():
    animals = [ ["cow", "moo"], ["pig", "neigh"], ["sheep", "bahh"] ]
    for animal in animals:
        print(verseFor(animal[0], animal[1]))
```

or you can use this method:

```
def main():
    animals = [
        {
            "name" : "cow",
            "sound": "moe"
        },
        {
            "name" : "pig",
            "sound": "haha"
        },
        {
            "name" : "dog",
            "sound": "lol"
        }
    ]
    for animal in animals:
        print(verseFor(animal["name"], animal["sound"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Janith said, you must concatenete string to strings. So to achive what you are trying to do you have to rewrite it like that:

```
lyrics = oldMacdonald() + "And on his farm he had a " + animal + ", Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!\n" \
        "With a " + sound[0] + ", " + sound[1] + " here and a " + sound[2] + ", " \
        "" + sound[3] + ".\nHere a " + sound[4] + ", there a " + sound[5] + ", " \
        "everywhere a " + sound[6] + ", " + sound[7] + "\n" + oldMacdonald()
```

But, there is an additional issue: You have only five animals with their 5 corresponding sounds, but you're placing 8 sounds on your lyrics....! so we are placing at least 3 extra "sounds" on the lyrics thing.
You may want to check one of the good python tutorials in the web, like the one in the official python web site https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/